# Async Request to API return undefined in Jest

Tags: jestjs

I am quiet new to testing, and specifically to Jest.
I am following several tutorials in which they handle asynchronous code in the manner I am attempting. My code seems to work when I am making a custom Promise that resolves with dummy data. But when I try to use axios to fetch from an external API, Jest gets as a response undefined.

```
// functions2.js
const axios = require("axios")

const fetch = () => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => err);
}

module.exports = fetch;
```

```
// functions2.test.js

describe("async operation", ()=>{
    it("should be defined", ()=>{
        expect(fetch).toBeDefined()
    }); // Passed

    it("should fetch", async () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        const data = await fetch();
        expect(data).toBeTruthy();
    }) // Did not pass, data is undefined

    it("should fetch, using promises", () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        return fetch().then(data => {
        expect(data).toBeTruthy();
        })  // Did not pass, got 0 assertions
    })
})
```

In one tutorial I encountered that this has something to do with Jest running through Node.JS, but I don't know how to handle it because I don't know node.js.

Also, I followed a tutorial by Traversy Media, cloned his Git repo (https://github.com/bradtraversy/jest_testing_basics) and had the same problem (though in the video it worked)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are not returning the promise from `fetch`.

Update your `functions2.js` to something like:

```
const fetch = async () => {
  return axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => err);
};
```